# Android - checking headset button click

Tags: android, implementation, headset

How can I checked if play/pause button in my headset is clicked?
After that can I implement some method that could change typical action (play/pause) for my own action (shut down etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to listen for this from an activity in the foreground, use `onKeyDown()` and watch for `KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE`.

Use a `BroadcastReceiver` for `ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON` if you are trying to listen for this event from the background (e.g., a service playing music).

Comment: It's my broadcast receiver but it doesn't work, what's wrong?
public final BroadcastReceiver hReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 String action = intent.getAction();
           
                 Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                 
                 if(mediaButtonIntent.equals(action))
                 {
                  adapter.add("click");
                 }
              
             }
         };

Comment: @user1320033: You do not need to test your action string, if you only use this `BroadcastReceiver` once with the right `IntentFilter`. Besides, you are testing it incorrectly.

Comment: @user1320033: `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())`.

Comment: It steal doesn't work :(
I write in onReceive: `if(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {...}`
and in onCreate()
`registerReceiver(hReceiver, new IntentFilter());` but after clicking nothing has happened.

Answer (score 5):

Right now I am using below code headset button click event it's working for me. try this code

```java
// Receiver
public class MediaButtonEventReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MediaButtonIntentReceiv";
    public MediaButtonIntentReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction = intent.getAction();
        if (!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)) {
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if (event == null) {
            return;
        }

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            // do something
            Log.e(TAG, "onReceive: " );
            Toast.makeText(context, "BUTTON PRESSED!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

```java
// Write this code in onCreateview in your activity 

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
MediaButtonIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonIntentReceiver();
filter.setPriority(1000); //this line sets receiver priority
registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

```xml
//  manifest.xml 
 <receiver android:name=".MediaButtonIntentReceiver">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON"/>
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON) intent
Read more above link
Hope this help

Comment: It's my broadcast receiver but it doesn't work, what's wrong?
public final BroadcastReceiver hReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
          public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 String action = intent.getAction();
           
                 Intent mediaButtonIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
                 
                 if(mediaButtonIntent.equals(action))
                 {
                  adapter.add("click");
                 }
              
             }
         };